# Trying to standardise UIView animations in my app, and it's not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have the same animation code applied to various views in my object, so i thought I would standardise it with it's own class. Here is the code i have:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AHAnimations : NSObject

+(void)popInView:(UIView *)view;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "AHAnimations.h"

@implementation AHAnimations

+(void)popInView:(UIView *)view {

    view.alpha = 0;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = 1;
                         view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                     }completion:nil];
}

@end
```

But instead of animating, the view just appears.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

EDIT: The original code is exactly the same. I can paste it, but other than being a different method name, i'd just be copying and pasting it from above. And now, it is simply `[AHAnimations popInView:view];`

Comment: Can you include the code where you create the view and call this code? And, if you still have it, the original code where you performed the whole thing and it worked?

Comment: I just tested your code snippet, worked just fine (btw probably you can add a category for UIView rather than creating a class for such a function). Question: how do you create a view which you are trying to pop, and how it is added to a parent view?

Comment: I create it with the standard `[UIView alloc] init...` and then `[self.view addSubview:view]`. It still isn't working for me, for some unknown reason.

Comment: How about this in your Root ViewController `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIView *pop = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    pop.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view addSubview:pop];
    [AHAnimations popInView:pop];
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc] init];
  [myview setFrame:CGRectMake( 50.0f, 50.0f, 280.0f, 400.0f)];
  [UIView commitAnimations]; 
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
  [myview setFrame:CGRectMake( 5.0f, 70.0f, 310.0f, 350.0f)];
```

// CALL This line to stop animation

```
 [myview.layer removeAllAnimations];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score -2):

`+[UIView animateWithDuration ...` not animating all properties, tho `alpha` should work...

Comment: transform and alpha are both animatable properties

Answer (score -2):

These code won't work, you can use CAAnimationGroup or CABasicAnimation's property: fromValue, byValue, toValue.

Also, you could implement like this which is easier to understand,

```
//go
- (void)stepOne{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stepTwo)];

    view.alpha = 0;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//back
- (void)stepTwo{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    view.alpha = 1;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);    
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

There are also a lot of original transition animation, you can check them out.

Comment: This method of animation is deprecated.

Comment: OK, not deprecated, but "discouraged"